# Transferir arquivo para o FTP e disponibiliza-lo para download automaticamente

Tags: php, javascript, html, ftp

Boa tarde!

Eu estou desenvolvendo um site, e to com algumas dúvidas. Nesse site vai ter uma página para download de alguns arquivos.

Eu gostaria de fazer o seguinte:

Quando transferir um arquivo para a pasta download no FTP, esse arquivo teria que aparecer automaticamente na minha página download para os usuários poderem baixar.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu posso fazer isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: Que tecnologias está a usar? Deve ser mais especifico em termos de descrição do que está ou quer usar.

Comment: Eu to usando php.

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver a usar PHP uma das soluções possíveis para a solução deste problema será criar uma pasta onde irá alojar todos os ficheiros para download e coloca-os na pasta via FTP.

Depois disto será apenas necessário criar um script que vai à pasta e lê todos os ficheiros dessa pasta e vai criando links para os mesmos à medida que estes são adicionados na pasta.

Por fim, apenas tem que gerar a interface que disponibiliza a lista de documentos e os respectivos links de download.

Comment: O problema é que eu não sei como fazer o script ler todos os arquivos da pasta.